# Display of text using random class

Tags: c#-4.0

i have a program that is supposed to display a certain text in a richtextbox based on what is already in the text box.The word supposed to display the rich text box is wrong but only when the text box displays d1.

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // richTextBox1.Text = "u1";
        int i = this.RandomNumber(0, 5);
        if (i > 2)
        {

            richTextBox1.Text = "u1";
        }

        else
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "d1";
        }
        }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // richTextBox1.Text = "Wrong";
    int i = this.RandomNumber(0, 5);  
        if (i<2)
        {

            richTextBox1.Text = "Right";
        }

            else

            {

                richTextBox1.Text = "Wrong";
   }

    }
```

The only problem is that the computer Doesn't use the same number

Comment: You are creating a new random # each time the button clicks. So, by clicking 'button5' it may give you a # <= 2, but it may create a # > 2 for 'button3'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling RandomNumber for each button click, so it's going to be different each time. It seems like you want something like:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // richTextBox1.Text = "u1";
    int i = this.RandomNumber(0, 5);
    if (i > 2)
    {

        richTextBox1.Text = "u1";
    }

    else
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "d1";
    }
}


private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// richTextBox1.Text = "Wrong";
    if (richTextBox1.Text.Equals("u1"))
    {

        richTextBox1.Text = "Right";
    }
    else
    {

            richTextBox1.Text = "Wrong";
    }
}
```